# GAE python Jinja2 multiple html same css file but only one html is rendered correctly

Tags: python, html, css, google-app-engine

I try building a small blog using Google App Engine, Python and Jinja2.
I have 3 different html files which refer to the same css file:

```
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

My app.yaml has the following declarations:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /css
  static_dir: templates/css

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

My problem is only one of my html files renders correctly! They are located in the same folder, namely "templates".
Any pointers to why this happens?
Thx

Comment: What are the other 2 page urk ? is it like http://localhost:8080/abc/abc ?

Comment: You should use absolute references for the link to the css resource.  What you have will break as soon a page is at the root level.

Comment: OK, I found the solution to my problem, my file front.html remained with css/index.css but in my other html files, namely newpost.html and permalink.html (all 3 html files are located in the same folder 'templates'), I changed the link reference to /css/index.css. It resolved my problem but I don't completely understand why, if you have a link to an explanation, i would be of interest, thx

Answer (score 1):

GAE is a bit different and that you have to explicitly tell it you want it to serve static files: css, images. etc. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles

First your handler in your app.yaml should look something like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
```

The /stylesheets would contain your CSS.  Now GAE will see you want to serve all the files in the path your-app/stlyesheets.

In this case your file structure would look like this:

```
your-app
 --main.py
 --app.yaml
 --stylesheets
   --style.css
 --templates
   --front.html
```

Now that the css is served you just reference it in your HTML

```
<link href="/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```